# Why would cv2.findEssentialMatrix return a 12x3 array?

Tags: python, camera-calibration, opencv

When using the function cv2.findEssentialMat, the output for E is a 12x3 array, when it should be a 3x3 array. By definition, essential matrices are 3x3.

I have tried altering the options/parameters, including method, threshold, and prob, but nothing seems to change the answer.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pOld = np.array(
   [[334.48077, 111.08635],
    [826.19525, 352.7404 ],
    [797.13354, 521.27057],
    [615.0971,  656.2975 ],
    [845.188,   173.10873]])

pNew = np.array(
    [[394.36942, 131.2731 ],
     [782.77637, 380.04907],
     [741.9934,  551.30444],
     [584.73315, 679.83984],
     [771.2071,  202.27649]])

K = np.array( \
    [[1.2112729e+03, 0.0000000e+00, 6.3218433e+02], \
     [0.0000000e+00, 1.2152592e+03, 3.4675201e+02], \
     [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00]])

E, mask = cv2.findEssentialMat(pOld, pNew, K, method=cv2.RANSAC, threshold=1.5, prob=0.99)


'''
Result:

E:
[[-0.00627753 -0.37505678 -0.07194276]
 [ 0.35912238  0.00781432 -0.60564749]
 [ 0.07145943  0.59419955  0.00994249]
 [ 0.34932297 -0.21108792 -0.41808301]
 [-0.02788446 -0.38781955  0.48859358]
 [ 0.27005355 -0.44238482 -0.00913568]
 [ 0.00870689  0.05265274 -0.08390127]
 [ 0.01960241  0.00364806 -0.70174221]
 [ 0.08495865  0.69993091  0.0123091 ]
 [ 0.3671368  -0.0009191  -0.52399762]
 [-0.12578615 -0.3897754  -0.35040367]
 [ 0.37598167  0.39838416  0.00585678]]

Mask:
[[1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

E should be returned as a 3x3 array. Strangely, there are no error messages.

## EDIT:

It seems that according to this https://answers.opencv.org/question/136092/findessentialmat-returns-3x30-or-3x12-mat/

A single solution for E is only possible with 8 point correspondences, and in my case I only have 5, leading to 4 possibilities.

Comment: I'd recommend you answer your own question instead of linking to another answer for OpenCV in your question ( which btw, is **not** a part of the stack exchange network, despite looking like it, so you have no fear of it being some sort of cross site-duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that according to this https://answers.opencv.org/question/136092/findessentialmat-returns-3x30-or-3x12-mat/

A single solution for E is only possible with 8 point correspondences, and in my case I only have 5, leading to 4 possibilities. Each 3x3 sub-array of the returned E is a unique essential matrix that was solved for.